# vba dateadd method drives me crazy

Tags: excel, vba, format, dateadd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpwCV.png)

It is results from the vba Direct Run window.
There is no operation in the screenshot above.
Is my Excel crazy?
Somebody please convince me.
Thank you.

Comment: What does `format(DateAdd("d",-2,now),"#.###")` give

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work. thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `DateAdd` to blame, it is yourself not knowing what `Now` and `Format` does.

`Now` contains a *time part* which you round up or down using `Format` and "#" (or "0").

So, use `Date`:

```
DateBeforeYesterday = DateAdd("d", -2, Date)
```

Comment: I feel ashamed, but your advice is perfect for me. thank you. I won't blame any computer function from now on......

Answer (score 0):

Excel represents date/time values as real numbers. The part to the left of the decimal point is the number of days since 12/30/1899.

```
? Format(0, "mm/dd/yyyy")
12/30/1899
```

The fractional part is the fraction of the day.

```
? format(.25, "hh:mm ampm")
06:00 AM

? format(.75, "hh:mm ampm")
06:00 PM
```

The following expressions are equivalent.

```
dt = DateAdd("d", -2, dateVal) 

dt = dateVal - 2
```